# Vue apex barchart gives error Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN NaNCNaN NaN …" when i add 0 in the series otherwise works fine

Tags: vuejs2, bar-chart, apexcharts

i am using vue apex bar chart and when i add 0 in series it gives this error Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN NaNCNaN NaN …" otherwise works fine                  this.series = [{ data: [1, 1, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1] }]
in this example it is wokrin fine but if i add 0 at any place it gives the error

I have tried all the solution given on the internet and they do not work

Comment: Try with 0.001 or even a smaller number.

Comment: works fine only gives error on 0

Comment: If you have time and desire - you could try to debug the library and see why it produces NaN. Perhaps you can even make a PR to the maintainer(s) with a bugfix.